# Obj-C Load Custom .plist file on load - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, uitableview

I'm looking to load a specific .plist file dependant on a settings variable (`area` in this case) and what button a user pressed. The file format for the .plist will be area-buttonPressed.plist. Below is the code that is used to call the specific .plist file (currently just dependant on the current area)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
self.navigationItem.title = @"Species List";

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    area  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"mulValue"];
    NSLog(@"Area is %@",area);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", area] ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"Path is %@",path);
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.names = dict;
    [dict release];
    NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.keys = array;
}
```

My main issue is that if I put the code that's currently in the viewWillAppear in the viewDidLoad, it won't get called again if I navigate back (I'm using a NavigationController), change the area in the settings and move to this viewController again. As a result, this method works great the first time I load this view, but it'll remain that way until I build my file again.

My main questions:

1. What is the correct way to set `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", area] ofType:@"plist"];`
    using 2 variables (settings variable area and the value of the button pressed in the last view (I have a NSString for that value))?
2. How do I update the *path every time the view is displayed?
3. If this would be a solution, how do I unload the view whenever the 'Back' button is pressed (this would solve the issue, because viewDidLoad gets called every time a user moves to this view, right?)

Below is the rest of my code:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [keys count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;
    }

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
    }

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    self.names = nil;
    self.keys = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [names release];
    [keys release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Some info on what my NSLog's say:

Whenever I press the button to load the table view, my console shows "viewWillAppear" and the `NSLog(@"Area is %@",area);` shows the correct area (Region1 in this case).

`NSLog(@"Path is %@",path);` either shows `(null)` when anything but Region1 is selected (I've only made Region1.plist so far), or iPhone Simulator/4.2/.../.../Region1.plist

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the problem with having the code in `viewWillAppear:`. `viewDidLoad` is called after your view has been either unarchived from a XIB or after `-loadView` depending on your approach.

If it needs to be updated every time the view appears, then `viewWillAppear:` is the correct place to put this code. If this fails to work, it's probably because the NSUserDefaults haven't had time to synchronize between being updated in your settings view and pushing back to this view. Typically, synchronization happens about every 30 seconds, but can be forced with `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`.

Comment: Note that when you're using NSUserDefaults, you can listen for the NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification to be informed specifically when the defaults have changed.

Comment: I agree that viewWillAppear should be the right place to do this. Also, the NSUserDefaults are synchronized (I'm using InAppSettingsKit). However, so far no luck. See my edit in the main post for some more info on the NSLogs.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what specific problem you are having, but do you think it could because you're attempting to load a .plist that doesn't exist? Thus `path` will be nil and `dict` will be nil resulting in `self.names` and `self.keys` also being nil.

Comment: The main issue was that the data in the table was not being updated when I changed the settings to a different region. However, I solved it by adding [table reloadData] to my viewWillAppear, which reloads all the data in the table. Now, if there is no plist available for the region, it just won't show any rows. Thanks for your help!